# How to disable CSS rule in Twentythirteen style.css?

Tags: plugins, themes, css

I have the following situation:

1. I have implemented a plugin [ChessTempoViewer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/chesstempoviewer/) that displays a chess game in a Wordpress page.
2. This plugin is working well in the themes 2010, 2012, 2014 but not in Twentythirteen.
3. The reason for that are the rules in `style.css` of that theme.

What are my options to remove these rules from the theme?

#### Details to the problem

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}
```

This leads to the following display of the chess board.

[image]

When i open the page e.g. in Chrome, and inspect there the HTML page, I am able to deselect the corresponding CSS rules, which results in a correct display.

[image]

Deselected the rules

[image]

Now displayed correct.

However, I am not able to add rules in my own CSS file that allow to suppress the rules. I have tried the following, but without effect.

```
.ct-black-square
{
    background-color: #88a0a9;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
}

.ct-white-square
{
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

What other options do I have to correct  the behavior of my plugin in the theme Twentythirteen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for box-sizing is content-box. This is applied when you deselect the rules in Chrome. Have you tried applying box-sizing: content-box in your own CSS file instead of inherit?

```
.ct-black-square
{
    background-color: #88a0a9;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}

.ct-white-square
{
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: I have tried it, but I don't get any difference in display. When I check the rules, the rules are applied to the board. So there seems to be a difference in not defining `box-sizing` to defining it with the value `content-box`.

Comment: This might be the solution: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24306#comment:5. I've tested this solution here: http://chesstempo.com/game-database.html. Setting box-sizing to content-box on the #board-boardBorder div worked.

Comment: Thank's a lot, that is the answer. I have added the following: .ct-black-square, .ct-white-square, .ct-board, .ct-board-boarder with your rules, and then the display worked in all themes.

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/plugins/chesstempoviewer/changelog/ for my change. Hope the new version 0.9.4 will be published soon :-)